# submitting ios app using the private key of a revoked distribution certificate

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, certificate-revocation

I have a distribution certificate that is still valid on my mac.

the team agent revoked it in the ios portal by mistake.

Am I still able to use the old certificate to submit apps to the app store? or should I get a new private key and provision profile of the new certificate?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Try it. When you archive the build in Xcode, you should always then validate the build before submitting it, so you'll soon see if there are any issues or not with the profiles etc.

Comment: thanks for your comment.. I tried and it didnt work. so we had to generate a new one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a new Distribution certificate (with a new private key) and any required provision files.

Answer (score 1):

My guess- you'll be able to use it to create a build but not submit to the store with it. For that you will need to recreate the mobileprovision with the new certificate.